# HTML5 SVG vs Canvas for big number of lines?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg, d3.js

Question:
  Is canvas more suitable than svg in the following case?

Case:
  I'm drawing a chart (using d3js library) similar to this one (but with much more data):

http://mbostock.github.com/d3/talk/20111116/iris-parallel.html

It's based on an svg and it works fine for several thousands of lines (up to 5000), adding more lines (svg path) decreases the performance dramatically (scrolling in the page becomes slow)

Keep in mind: That I need to add mouse events (which is handy in svg)

Comment: Depends on how the lines are drawn: Is it possible to combine more lines to a single path or polygon element, reducing the number of DOM elements? This might possibly give some performance increase - it's at least worth a try.

Comment: @ThomasW - +1.  I've found this helps enormously in improving performance of SVG-based visualizations.  In any event, your user can't sensibly perceive tens of thousands of lines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally `svg` is better suited for vector images, like in your example. However `canvas` has a lot of benefits in modern browsers such as hardware acceleration, so for drawing the lines, as long as zooming, panning ect. isn't required performance will be using `canvas`.

Mouse events can be a pain using `canvas`, since you have to manually keep track of everything, so with 5000+ points using `canvas` it wont be fun. The trade off however will be once the points are drawn, assuming you only draw them once the page will behave fine regardless of the number of lines, since they are all drawn to a raster image and aren't part of the `DOM`.

Honestly though the best way to find it is to test what you currently have using canvas.

Comment: 1. Thank you :D, 2. Mouse events are related to the axes not the data points, so, in my case I have under a 100 axes, 3. Implementing what I have in Canvas is not straight forward and may take time that's why I asked in the first place, 4. Thanks again :D

Comment: As I posted in my answer, you can draw an SVG to a canvas using the drawImage method, so you don't even have to re-implement your drawing code.

Comment: Thank you but how can I use drawImage? can you give me a snippet?

Answer (score 5):

When performance becomes a problem, switching to canvas might be an option. In this case you can draw the canvas once. Afterwards it's pretty much treated like an image. Drawing might take some time, but afterwards it can be scaled pretty quickly. Note that it is possible to draw a rendered SVG to a canvas using the context.drawImage method ([example](http://www.phrogz.net/tmp/canvas_from_svg.html)). So you could keep your SVG generation code to create an SVG in the background, and then draw it to the canvas.

But keep in mind that it won't scale as beautiful as an SVG as soon as it is on the canvas. When the user zooms in, it will get blurry or pixely, depending on how the browser scales graphics.

Click events on canvas can be handled in two ways. Either keep an array of click targets, and add an onclick event handler to the canvas. When a click occurs, iterate the array and check which one is closest to the click coordinates.

The other option is to use [hit regions](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#hit-regions). These have to be defined as polygonal paths.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was very helpful. I don't need scaling so I am not afraid of getting blurry, the only thing that will be painful is mouse event (clicking and hovering)

Comment: It's probably quite possible to use canvas and svg together, e.g stack them on top of each other and let the svg side handle the interaction. Or to draw the static content into a canvas, use getDataURL to get the rasterized result and then use that in an <svg:image> element.

Comment: @AhmedMoawad I found out that drawing dynamically generated SVGs to a canvas isn't as trivial as I promised. But I managed to do it with some tricks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13963259/drawing-a-modified-svg-to-a-canvas/13999263#13999263

Answer (score 2):

+1 to everything said above. I've seen some amazing performance increases when using canvas over SVG and over compositing images using the DOM.

About manipulating the canvas image with mouse events, I imagine the best approach for an image such as you are describing is to abstract it away using a library like the following:

- http://paperjs.org
- http://kineticjs.com
- http://www.createjs.com/#!/EaselJS

Keep your code away from the canvas itself and let a library do the thinking for you.

Comment: The canvas APIs are a pretty simple. If you don't need a full scene graph implementation, I'd recommend and a handful of [custom helper functions](https://github.com/forresto/web-interactive-workshop#processing-not-processing) that you write yourself over a library.

Comment: +1 for using the "native" API over a library if the scene is simple